# How to limit cpu usage for a terminal command that works on m1 mac and macOS Monterey?

Tags: ffmpeg, terminal, cpu-usage, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I have a m1 macbook pro and I regularly need to do some heave processing with `ffmpeg`. When I do it, all my 8 cores go at it 100% and my cpu temperature goes to 92°C, which I don't feel comfortable about.

I don't really need 100% speed, I'd much rather see 80°C and wait 5x longer for it to finish.

I use Macs Fan Control which sets my fan at 100% at 75°C, so this helps definitely, but is not enough.

I tried `ffmpeg -threads 1` parameter but it doesn't make a difference in compressing speed nor temperature, so I assume it just doesn't work.

I tried `cpulimit -l 60 -i ffmpeg ...` and it doesn't change a thing, so I assume it also doesn't work. `cpulimit -l` value gives 100% for every core, so `cpulimit -l 800` should be 100%, `-l 400` should be 50% and `-l 60` should be 7.5%.

I tried `nice` and it is not for my use case. Even with the lowest priority the task uses all available cpu, resulting in 92°C.

Did anybody figure it out for m1 macs already?

Answer (score 0):

So I tried running `cpulimit -l 10 -i ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vcodec libx264 -crf 24 output.mp4` and it actually slowed down the cpu.

The cpu usage (all cores) was between 60-70% and temperature also was about 60-65°C.
[image]

The compressing speed went down from about 3.5-4.0x to 2.0-2.5x, so very minimally.

`-l 10` should mean 1.25% cpu theoretically. I don't know why, but this is usable.

Comment: I'm not gonna mark my answer as accepted in the hope that someone has a proper answer or can explain what is going on. But in the meantime you can try this solution and it will probably get the job done.

Comment: thanks for the help. I had exactly the same issue. I have tried cpulimit -l 60 and 40 but no difference, still use full cpu usage, so I thought the tool is broke somehow for M1. then I saw your solution, tried -l 10 and it works, don't know why though but as you said, it is usable :)